# how to read xml response returned from a third party webservice that i m consuming in my application

Tags: c#, service, web

I am new to web services, I am getting a "response not well formed XML" exception from a third party web service that I am consuming in my code.

Can someone tell me a way to take a look at the XML, may b storing it in a text file or log file or something like that. I have seen a few help topics on this forum as well as other forums where they have the same error, but also post their response XML asking for help. I have no idea how to get the response XML, so that i can see what the issue is.

Thanks,

Phani.

Comment: Have a look at 'System.Diagnostics" and tracing messages http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I do not have access to web service code, I have an application that creates an object for a class in the webserivce and invokes a method, and I get an exception because that webservice is not returning me XML properly, what you are suggesting is to modify the web service to add message logging, which i cannot do. Let me know if i interpreted you incorrectly.....

Comment: Ehh. that was not what i was suggesting, modify the client to do the tracing.